# Clustering key, value pairs with similar meanings

Tags: deep-learning, pattern-recognition, clustering

I have a dataset of key-value pairs that describe specific medical laboratory mappings. Example of this data:

| Group Name | Specific Test Name |
| --- | --- |
| Blood Test | Red Blood Cells |
| Blood Test | Hemoglobin |
| Complete Blood Test | RBC |
| Complete Blood Test | WBC |
| Blood Test Platelet | WBC |
| Blood Test Platelet | Platelet Count |
| PSA Total | PSA |

As it can be seen, the top 6 rows are all talking about a blood test, while the last row is talking about an unrelated PSA test. In row #1 and row #3, "Red Blood Cells" and "RBC" mean the same thing.

I am trying to leverage machine learning and pattern-recognition to model this data and put the top 6 rows in one group (even though they spell the same thing differently) and the last row in a different group.

So far, I have tried to use K-Means clustering with TF-IDF and have also looked into Self Organizing Maps, but I have not been successful in either one of them. For K-means specifically, I am struggling with converting the textual data into integers so they can be consumed by the algorithms.

My question is -

1. Is it possible to achieve what I want in terms of "intelligently clustering" the 6 rows together?
2. If so, how do I go about it?

Comment: Can you please put your **specific question** in the title?